# Implementation of spring batch to run a background process

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, parallel-processing, spring-batch

I am trying to implement spring batch but I have few questions. Please find below my code.

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml (I am adding the content I have added as part of spring batch)

```
<!--  Spring Batch implementation starts -->
```

```
<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="simpleJob" class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob" abstract="true">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
<!-- Spring Batch implementation ends  -->
```

Spring-batch.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org  /schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

   <import resource="classpath:spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml"/>

 <bean id="customReader" class="com.batchjob.CustomItemReader" >
    <property name="userId" value="#{jobParameters['userId']}" > </property>
</bean>



     <bean id="customProcessor" class="com.batchjob.CustomItemProcessor" />

    <bean id="customWriter" class="com.batchjob.CustomItemWriter" />   

  <bean id="simpleStep" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleStepFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />

    <property name="itemReader" ref="customReader"/>
    <property name="itemProcessor" ref="customProcessor"/>
    <property name="itemWriter" ref="customWriter"/>

    <property name="commitInterval" value="2" />
</bean>

<bean id="readerWriterJob" parent="simpleJob">
    <property name="steps">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleStep"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

CustomItemReader.java

```
 package com.batchjob;

import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
 import com.beans.UserLogin;



 public class CustomItemReader implements ItemReader<UserLogin> {

 @Autowired
 private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
 private String username;
  @Override
  public UserLogin read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
        ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

    System.out.println("In DaoImpl of user login");
    String sql = "select * from USERS where user_name=? ";
    try {
        return (UserLogin) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,
                new Object[] { (username) }, new RowMapper<UserLogin>() {
                    @Override
                    public UserLogin mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                            throws SQLException {
                        UserLogin userLoginDetails = new UserLogin();
                        userLoginDetails.setUserName(rs
                                .getString("user_name"));
                        userLoginDetails.setPassword(rs
                                .getString("user_password"));
                        userLoginDetails.setRole(rs.getString("user_role"));
                        userLoginDetails.setFullName(rs
                                .getString("user_fullname"));
                        return userLoginDetails;
                    }
                });
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }

   }
   }
```

CustomItemProcessor.java

```
 package com.batchjob;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;

public class CustomItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Object, Object> {

@Override
public Object process(Object arg0) throws Exception {


    // how to get all the values that customItemReader have fetched from the table ?


    // perform some more activity

    return null;
 }

 }
```

CustomItemWriter.java

```
package com.batchjob;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import com.bean.UserLogin;

public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<UserLogin> {
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
UserLogin userloginObj;
String status="Success";

@Override
public void write(List arg0) throws Exception {

userloginObj.setStatus(status);
String sql = "update table_name set status=?";

        try {

            jdbcTemplate.update(sql,
                    new Object[] { userloginObj.getStatus()});

        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```

Controller code:

```
     public void addUserDetails(@RequestParam("name") String username,
        @RequestParam("fullname") String fullname,
        @RequestParam("role") String role,
        @RequestParam("loginPassword") String loginPassword,
        @RequestParam("userStatus") String userStatus  ) {

    try {

        adduser.setUserName(username);
        adduser.setFullName(fullname);
        adduser.setLoginPassword(loginPassword);
        adduser.setUserStatus(userStatus);
        adduser.setRole(role);

        userLoginDAOImpl.insertAddUserDetails(adduser);


      here i have to run the job that i don'nt know how to run it. like this i am doing in my demo code. (Here also if i write a function to invoke this job that should run in background)



  String[] springConfig = { "batch-job.xml" };

  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
   ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

 JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
 Job job = (Job) context.getBean("testJob");

 try {

    JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("age", "20").toJobParameters();

    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
    System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
    System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getAllFailureExceptions());

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
   System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

     }
   }
```

Now I have 2 questions
Q.1 How to run this job in my controller so that satatment should run in background I mean below should start execution they should not wait for above statement to complete.

Q2. ItemReader, pre-processor and itemWriter code that I have written I am not sure it is correct can any one verify it?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

You can configure spring batch with `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` and than you can invoke spring batch job execution which will run in background (so you will have some activity -> trigger job execution in background -> do other activity), something like:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
    final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
    return jobLauncher;
}
```

**Option 2**

As you said you can save parameters in DB, but spring batch has all infrastructure to save statuses etc. I would suggest not to reinvent the wheel but use [spring scheduling mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) to check DB table for new parameters, if they are there launch job with one of implementations of `ItemReader` which reads from DB, do processing and in writer update DB in results.

Here is link to [Spring batch samples on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples) which is great starting place with many examples.

Comment: i want to go with option 1 can u please explain how i will proceed i mean in my controller i am invoking script instead of that i need to create new JobLauncher class and what kind of changes needs to do in my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml or i need to create another xml file for job. If you can tell few steps it would be great

Comment: It would be too long to explain all about spring batch. Internet is full of it. I would do couple of things (just idea approach): 1. Familiarize with spring batch and create job which is needed as standalone app https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ 2. Make endpoint in my spring batch app which will invoke batch job with launcher (or with message depending on yourarchitecture) 3. Configure async task processor 4. In controller use http client or something to call batch app and start job

Comment: Nenad can you pls look to the updated code if possible?